# Shorting isset POST?

Tags: php

I have many isset checkings:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['day']) && isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email2'])&& isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['pass2']))
{
```

Is there a way to short it?

```
$isset = array
(
    'name', 'day', 'month', 'year',
    'email', 'email2', 'pass', 'pass2'
);

foreach ($isset As $set)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$set]) || empty($_POST[$set]))
    {
        echo 'error';
        break;
    }
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: it is the right way of checking each post

Comment: You could always use `!empty()` however this will return false positives for falsy values

Comment: Is it the same as isset()?

Comment: unless you name everything the same with an increasing number at the end; the way you got is the shortest way to check these variables.

Comment: don't use `empty()`, especially you're dealing with numbers. `empty(0)` is actually TRUE in php.

Comment: instead of `empty()` you might want to use `$set == NULL` or `$set == ''`

Comment: @JoshBalcitis - other than warnings about undefined indices, `empty()` and `$foo == NULL` will return the exact same thing in all cases.

Comment: @Sam Dufel: empty does not do any warnings.

Comment: Before asking a question please take a look for existing solutions for your problem and then - if they don't work for you - ask more specifically for your case and telling what didn't work for you so far. E.g. with your edited question, it's not clear what your issue is even. What is your *concrete programming problem*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a loop and `empty` only:

```
$keys = array('name', 'day', 'month');  // ...

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
    // fail
    break;
  }
}
```

Or you could use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key):

```
if (array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), $_POST)) {
  // fail (some keys not present in $_POST)
}
```

Comment: Look at my edit, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but beware that `empty` will match `0` too (may fail with checkboxes). If that's a valid value you should stick to `isset()` only and do individual checks later. Also, `isset()` is redundant if you use `empty`

Comment: So that means I can just use empty() instead?

Comment: Yes, but I suggest you check the manual page for [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) first to see what values are considered "empty"

Comment: To use `empty` with the 2nd method: `array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), array_filter($_POST))` (`array_filter` will drop items that are empty)

Comment: Does this method really shorten it though?  What if you had 1000 keys? Are you going to write them all out in the array $keys?  That doesn't seem shorter.  You're just transferring the length from one place to the other.

Comment: It's still shorter than writing 1000 issets

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` can take multiple arguments, so you can shorten it simply like this.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['email2'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['pass2']))
```

PHP Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 3):

Define a function like this:

```
function getPost($key, $default = null) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Then you can skip the isset verification. If there's no sucho value, by default, the function will return `null`.

Comment: If you did this you would only get one return value for each key/function pair.  How would you then use this?  Foreach($_POST as $key) $SomeArray[$key] = getPost($key, $default)?  The thing that is missing here, is that even if a $_POST value is "" it still is technically set.  So literally every post value would return true in that function.  All you'd really be doing is changing $_POST to $Something, and the keys would be identical, with identical values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending these from an input form and your default value attribute is value="" then it will still be set in $_POST.

For example, if the previous page has:

```
<input type="text/css" id="email" name="email" value="" />
```

Then if the user leaves it blank, isset($_POST['email']) will return true, and $_POST['email'] will have a value of "".  That's useless, right?

Try this.

```
$c = 0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$value = trim($value);//Makes sure there's no leading, or ending spaces.  Safe to guard against a string that is " " instead of "".
if(strlen($value) > 0)
    {
    $c++;
    }
else
    {
    echo "$_POST['" . $key . "'] has a problem.";
    }
break;
}
```

Then your new if statement for whatever conditions you had in mind could be:

```
if($c == 8)//8 being the number of keys you're expecting to not be "" or null.
{
//Your conditions.
}
```

This is good to keep in mind.  You are only testing 8 array keys, but what if you had 800?  Something like this would be a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are doing, if it is to set a value, the ternary operator works wonders:

```
isset($_POST['day'])?$day=_POST['day'] :$day='';
```

after that line, $day is always set and you only test with if($day).

If there are many values, you can always run this assignment in a loop:

```
foreach(array('day','month','name') as $var)
{
  isset($_POST[$var])?$$var=$_POST['$var']:$$var='';
}
```